# ASP.NET MVC AJAX Calendar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, calendar

I am currently learning ASP.NET MVC and I have followed Stephen Walther's tutorial: [ASP.NET MVC Tip #36 – Create a Popup Calendar Helper](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/22/asp-net-mvc-tip-36-create-a-popup-calendar-helper.aspx).

The calendar is working, but I would like to change the date format to dd/mm/yyyy.

Also are you able to add arrows at the top, so that the calendar can be changed by year as well as month?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know this is probably for learning purposes, but a good solution already exists: [JQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Comment: Thank you. I used the JQuery UI DatePicker and now have the calendar working.

Comment: Is there a demo of how the DatePicker works with data from a database? For example you have a table with events in it and want to render this in the DatePicker to link to a page with the event details?

Answer (score -1):

index.cs

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public string StartDate { get; set; }
```

index.cshtml

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartDate)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.